# Download an entire dynamic site

Tags: dynamic

I have developed a site with cake-php. It works pretty well, it regards a soccer championship, now that the season is ended there's no need of dynamic interaction. I would donwload  all the site to avoid unusefull mysql call and so on.
What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Use `wget` - here's an [article](http://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/create-a-mirror-of-a-website-with-wget/) describing what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Log into the FTP of the website and from there download everything. Do note that if you want to save your SQL database you will need to log into the database itself (often - if not always - via the website of your host).

EDIT: for a static copy, you can use HTTrack. Quite a useful tool with a lot of options and it's free:
http://www.httrack.com/

Comment: Exact, I already have the source and the entire mysql dump.

Comment: In that case: see edit in my post.